# MVC4 Partial view not loading values into "container" model on post back

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I want to create a re-usable view for editing an Address, phone number, etc.

I setup a Container Model that contains all the Models needed.
Created a partial view to handle the Address part of th
e form

But when it posts back to the controller, customer data is there from the main page, but anything from the partial views is not there (using MVC4/Razor)

Container Model

```
public class CustomerViewModel {
    public Customer CustomerData { get; set; }
    public Address MainAddress { get; set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public Phone MainPhone { get; set; }
    public Phone Fax { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0) {
    CustomerViewModel model = new CustomerViewModel();
    model.CustomerData = Customer.FetchById(id);
    if (model.CustomerData == null) return HttpNotFound();

    //... load addresses, phones

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerViewModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ///... save everything here - model has CustomerData, but nothing else
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Main View:

```
@model ProjectName.WebSite.Models.CustomerViewModel

.....

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelCustomer.CustomerId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelCustomer.CompanyName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelCustomer.CompanyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelCustomer.CompanyName)
        </div>

        ...        

        @Html.Partial("Address", Model.MainAddress, new ViewDataDictionary {
            TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Main" }
        })

        ...        

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
.....
```

Address Partial View:

```
@model ProjectName.Business.Address

<fieldset style="margin-top:  20px;">
    <legend>@(ViewData["label"] ?? "Address")</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Street)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Street)
    </div>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

What am I doing wrong here - why can I not get the Model populated from the partial views?

Comment: If you answered this question yourself please provide an answer (BELOW) and accept it so the question is marked Answered.

Comment: @Nayt, kingdango is right.  Please move the portion of your question marked "SOLVED IT" as a new answer below.  After doing so, please mark it as the accepted answer.  One cool result of doing so is that others may find your answer useful too; if they do, they'll upvote your answer, which is one of the fun things about participating on this site.

Comment: I think you'd better use an EditorTemplate for the Adress type here. This would avoid you a lot of trouble when maintaining your code in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SOLVED IT!** I figured it out! Could not sleep, and just stumbled on it!

In the View you have to make sure that the HtmlFieldPrefix uses the same name as in your composite model class, so since I named the two addresses as "MainAddress" and "ShippingAddress" - just have to make sure the same name is used when setting up the Partial:

```
@Html.Partial("Address", Model.MainAddress, new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData) {
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "MainAddress" }
})

@Html.Partial("Address", Model.ShippingAddress, new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData) {
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "ShippingAddress" }
})
```

Comment: I had the exact problem and stumbled upon this post before I was about to ask a similar question myself. I was doing everything you were except that in my @Html.Partial("Address", Model.ShippingAddress) I wasn't using the third ViewDataDictionary input parameter, and was having the same problem you had upon postback. Why is this ViewDataDictionary portion "required" - in my case I only have 1 type of address, not multiple types like you - so just saying "Model.MainAddress" should suffice in my case, I'd imagine? (Yes, everything worked well upon including this 3rd input parameter).

Comment: Even though you only have one address - the 3rd parameter still tells the code which property of your view contains the address, in this case "MainAddress" is the property of the view that contains an AddressView object...